# Crear formulario coincidiendo los inputs con la imagen de fondo

Tags: html, css

Intento realizar un formulario que coindide codo con un fondo que tiene la página. Me explico

El fondo es un diseño en una imagen que ya tiene todo creado por ejemplo:
Nombre: ________________ Edad: ____
Localidad: ________________ Pais: _______

Todo esoo está en un fondo y lo que quiero es que los inputs coincidan con los huecos que hay en el diseño que está en el fondo

¿ Cuál es la mejor forma para realizar esto ? A mi solo se me ha ocurrido ponerles una posicion fija metiendoles los px exactos del fondo.

Pero claro...esto una vez se reduzca la web y la imagen se modifique a los anchos dejará de coincidir por lo que solo funcionaria en versión de escritorio.

Comment: Ahí tienes que hacer uso de diferentes imágenes según los breakpoints del navegador, con reglas media query. Así tienes exactitud de los pixeles a ocupar dependiendo de la resolución. Es lo que yo haría

Comment: Pero cual es la mejor forma de hacer loq ue he comentado ? poniendo las coordenadas en px por css en cada input ?

Comment: Y no es mejor crear la imagen basándose en el diseño de los inputs? Porque con la opción que te comento deberías tener unas 4 imágenes aprox. Yo las mandaría como background de un contenedor con tamaño fijo y ahí dentro los inputs.

Comment: @Rodrypaladin ¿solo será para llenarlo en computadoras de escritorio (laptop,etc)? o ¿también en dispositivos móviles? Ya que si es una sola imagen veo demasiados problemas. O ¿tienes diferentes imagenes? ¿Que otras alternativas tienes?

Comment: Sería para rellenarlo desde cualquier dispositivo, estoy pensando también en hacer un pdf rellenable y embedirlo a la web, pero en dispositivos moviles estamos en las mismas

Comment: @Rodrypaladin ¿Podrías explicarme porque es necesaria la imagen? para así poder pensar en una solución ¿Es por los logotipos o porque así lo requiere el cliente?

Comment: @Abner Es una plantilla para mandar una carta de forma online en la que solo tiene que rellenar los campos, y el fondo es una imagen, que tiene que coincidir con las lineas de la carta, e imagenes decorativas

Comment: @Rodrypaladin hay varias formas de hacer lo que pides, creo que deberías ampliar tu pregunta añadiendo lo que llevas o las alternativas que te has planteado, para así tener un punto de dónde arrancar.